# Recognizing fake NEO-M8N gps module?

Tags: esp32, gps

I bout a NEO-M8N gps module but I can't connect to u-blox softwares (both u-center2 & u-center_v22.07)

It seems to be one of the junk modules that China mass-produces

Module's pictures :

[image]

[image]

I tried **TinyGPSPlus**, **Sparkfun u-blox** and some other libraries to connect it to my **ESP32 Dev. Board (30 pin board)** but i cant programme it,
Also i connected to my laptop USB port directly but i even can't see  it coming up to my device manager list (not even as unknow device)
All i can see is the onboard LED turning On when i connect it

Is there any **Arduino sketch** to recognise it (recognise it's core) to find it's library? Or is there any **free windows software** to recognise all gps modules?
And then, how can i programme it to connect esp32 and give me lat, long & alt as float numbers?

**Note :** i have **ESP32 Dev. Kit (30 pin)** as my only controller so, any suggestion sketch must be compatible with the board

Comment: sounds like the module has failed

Comment: There is a very simple Arduino program you can try here: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/guide-to-neo-6m-gps-module-with-arduino/ . You'll have to adapt it for the ESP32 to use one of the ESP32's other serial ports instead of using the SoftwareSerial library. Note that TX and RX are crossed. This may help if there is a problem only with the device's USB interface.

Comment: I'm using Neo-M8N-0-10 not Neo-6m

Answer (score -1):

just plug the unit to terminal software, set the baud to 9600 and see what is coming out.

you can even use Arduino IDE, if the unit is not faulty, you should be able to see data coming out.

I use Neo8M & Neo6M, all bought from AliXpress, not a single failed so far.

Comment: didn't get anything

Comment: and about connecting and getting data from Arduino IDE, it's not make sense because in the IDE you have to select the board and it doesn't support any gps module as far as i know

Comment: I am using Arduino IDE to test the serial data from GPS.  just plug in the GPS module, if windows(I assume you are using windows) detects the port, that particular port will appear in the port list on the arduino ide. just select the port and open the serial monitor.  data should be flowing in.  if the port does not appear in your IDE, most likely windows does not recognise the port, ie port is faulty or the gps module is faulty.  hope this helps.